# I tried writing a code which have a function with if else loop. I wanted a counter of the number of times that if statement is ran

Tags: python, nuke

Please help me. I wanted the counter num variable to add everytime the function is ran. But its not working, please tell me why I did wrong. If I use return num then the code is ending which I dont want, but n =+1 is not working, please help. Thanks a lot.

```
def prompt():
num = 1
print(num)
question = input("Do you want to add a file(y,n): ")

if question == "y":


    file = input("Which File?: ")
    nukefile.append(file)
    st_frm = input("Start frame: ")
    start_frame.append(st_frm)
    en_frm = input("End Frame: ")
    end_frame.append(en_frm)

    #return num + 1

    num =+1 
    print(num)

    nukew = str("start /wait Nuke11.1.exe -x -"+st_frm+"-"+en_frm+" "+file)
    nukewrite.append(nukew)
    que = (str(num)+". "+file+"--"+st_frm+","+en_frm)
    for_artist.append(que)


    for x in for_artist:
        print(x)

    prompt()
    return num


elif question == "n":
    print(nukewrite)
    f = open(batchfile, "a")
    for shotsa in nukewrite:
        f.write('\n'+shotsa+'\n')
    print("Following files will render:")
    for shotsb in nukefile:
        print(shotsb)
    
    f.close()
else:
    print("Invalid entry")
    prompt()
```

Comment: this is the code, please tell me where I did I go wrong.

Comment: You're using recursion to `prompt()` to display the new prompt, so `num` is newly initialized at each call. You probably want a while loop instead of a recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count how many times the function runs and keep it recursive, you'll need to define `prompt.num` outside of `prompt`. You can define it under the function or use a decorator and define it above.

```
def prompt():
    prompt.num += 1
    your code

prompt.num = 0
```